# Twitter Api Client: works Locally but not in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter

I am relatively new to Ruby and Programming in General.  I have created this App about 6months ago which searches the top twitter and google trends to output a JSON file of all the most popular videos in youtube.  I had deployed it to Heroku and had no problems until twitter api 1 updated to api 1.1.  6 months ago to get the twitter trends which worked locally and in heroku, my code looked like this..

```
    if trendLocation == nil
        result = JSON.parse(open("https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json").read)
    end

    if trendLocation.to_i == 23424977
        result = JSON.parse(open("https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424977.json").read)
    end

    topTen = result.first["trends"]
    panelArray = Array.new
```

(https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424977.json) Used to be an open source which directly gives me the top trends in twitter (no authentication needed).  Ever-since the Twitter API 1.1 update, the link no longer exist and I had to authenticate my app to get the trends. Now Every-time I called for twitter trends in the Url, my app crashes.  But when I call for the google trends, it works perfectly fine locally and in Heroku.

So I downloaded the 'twitter' and 'oauth' gem to authenticate my app using Twitter::Client. I changed my code to this.

```
def getPanelsForTwitter(panelMaxCount)

    client = Twitter::Client.new(
        :consumer_key => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        :consumer_secret => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        :oauth_token => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        :oauth_token_secret => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    )

    usa = client.trends(23424977)
    world = client.trends(1)

    trendLocation = params[:woeid]

    if trendLocation == nil
        result = world
    end

    if trendLocation.to_i == 23424977
        result = usa
    end

    panelArray = Array.new      

end
```

Everything works locally and does everything it needs to do (like get the twitter and google trends, search it on youtube, and display the video results). But when I pushed it to Heroku, the app crashes and  but does not work when I push or deploy it to Heroku.

I ran heroku logs and this is what I get

---

```
2013-10-13T19:38:31.623556+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-10-13T19:38:31.623556+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-10-13T19:38:31.631953+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635716+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635716+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635670+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- oAuth (LoadError)
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.635811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636437+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.4/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636437+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-10-13T19:38:31.636437+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-10-13T19:38:33.267427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-13T19:38:33.252069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-10-13T19:38:35.105276+00:00 heroku[run.1165]: Awaiting client
2013-10-13T19:38:35.237705+00:00 heroku[run.1165]: Starting process with command `bundle`
2013-10-13T19:38:37.592953+00:00 heroku[run.1165]: State changed from starting to complete
2013-10-13T19:38:37.583575+00:00 heroku[run.1165]: Process exited with status 0
2013-10-13T19:38:51.535832+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/trends?p=10&v=10&source=gt&woeid=23424977 host=radiant-plains-2608.herokuapp.com fwd="50.129.228.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
129.228.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-13T19:37:58.326215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

========================================================================

The first error I get is (3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- oAuth (LoadError)).

So I'm assumming something is wrong with my gems, I'm thinking the gems locally and gems in heroku do not match.

here is my gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
    activesupport (3.2.9)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    faraday (0.8.5)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
    hike (1.2.1)
    httpauth (0.2.0)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.6)
    jwt (0.1.5)
      multi_json (>= 1.0)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.5.0)
    multi_xml (0.5.3)
    multipart-post (1.1.5)
    nokogiri (1.5.6)
    oauth (0.4.7)
    oauth2 (0.9.1)
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      httpauth (~> 0.1)
      jwt (~> 0.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    pg (0.14.1)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.4)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.9)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      activerecord (= 3.2.9)
      activeresource (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.9)
    railties (3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.5)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    simple_oauth (0.2.0)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    thor (0.17.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    twitter (4.8.1)
      faraday (~> 0.8, < 0.10)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simple_oauth (~> 0.2)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    youtube_it (2.1.13)
      builder
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.2)
      oauth (~> 0.4.4)
      oauth2 (~> 0.6)
      simple_oauth (>= 0.1.5)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  oauth
  pg
  rails (= 3.2.9)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  twitter (>= 4.8.1)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  youtube_it
```

Everything matches when I run gem list locally and when I run heroku run gem list.  I tried uninstalling the 'twitter' and 'oauth' gems, and reinstalling it and ran bundle install, but still having the same issue.

At this current state, my app only works locally and does not work in Heroku (live) at all, even when Im trying to get the google trends only. The whole app crashes.

When I rolled back to six months ago in Heroku, the app only crashes when Im calling something from twitter.  Everything else works live in Heroku.

This leads me to believe, its a Heroku deployment issue when it's trying to read the gemfile. Right?  Am I missing anything? are there other gems I could possibly use? or is this not a gem issue?

github: https://github.com/meeks16/webservice

Thanks

Comment: what is not working? what happens when you deploy it on heroku? can you post heroku logs?

Comment: Did you go into dev.twitter.com and update the callback URL? Maybe it's redirecting to your localhost after user approval. (I think your oAuth library can optionally specify a callback URL, but if not, it will redirect back to the one you included in settings.)

Comment: register 2 apps on twitter. 1 for development and 1 for your live app, and put the keys and secret into environment variables

Comment: its also a very bad idea to have the api keys in a public repository... you should always use ENV variables for this purpose

Comment: you gotta show the logs mate!  type heroku logs from your terminal/command prompt from the project root and paste the log here. or else, open config/environments/production.rb and set config.consider_all_requests_local to true.  deploy your changes and when you visit the site again, you'll see a detailed error message.  post it here, when you get the error message.

Comment: @rb512 I've just edited my post adding a couple of things including a copy of my heroku logs. And the first error I'm getting is an oauth load error.  Thank you so much.

Comment: as for your first issue, you might wanna take a look at this thread :https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/193.  mahemoff and AJcodez rightly pointed out that the issue might be due to an incorrect callback URL.

Comment: @mahemoff thank you for your response.  I already have a specific callback URL which is the home page of my app (radiant-plains-2608.herokuapp.com).  So I am thinking this might not be the issue. In my heroku logs the first error is theat comes up is  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- oAuth (LoadError)  could this be a path issue?

Comment: @rb512 thank you for the link, and I already have a callback URL.  I've looked through my gem list locally and in heroku and my gems including the oauth gem versions are identical.  I uninstalled the oauth, run bundle locally and in heroku, and I still have the same error (No file to load --oAuth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your input. Finally found what was wrong with this. It was very careless of me but it was a simple syntax error.  My error in heroku logs was..

```
`rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- oAuth (LoadError)
```

I had a separate temps_controller that had a require 'oAuth' that I totally forgot about. The gem 'oAuth' does not exist it was suppose to be 'oauth'.  This is why the app crashes when deployed to heroku. Im a little surprised and puzzled why it worked locally. I am guessing localhost is more forgiving with mistakes like these?

I should really be careful when Im deploying to a live site.  Making sure to clean my code, by removing all temporary files I used for testing.  Maybe avoid using require in controllers.  Just install the gem needed.

It was such a simple and silly mistake which took me a bit of time, but definitely learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got some good answers in the comments, but you may also want to look at a **[Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)** to ensure you're not throwing your public API keys around where they could be compromised